# Twitter-bootstrap-3 | Thumbnail Centering?

Tags: center, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Hey Guys!**

I'm currently working on a website using twitter bootstrap 3 but I've got some issues. I'm trying to center the 3 thumbnails I've got. The text is centered, image is centered but I can't seem to get the thumbnails centered. Here is my code:

```
       <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
       <div class="thumbnail">    
  <img src="img/test.png">
        <div class="caption">
    <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
 <img src="img/test.png">
        <div class="caption">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="img/test.png>
        <div class="caption">
          <p>test</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .thumbnail {
    background-color: #cecece;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is not centred from your code. Also see: http://bootply.com/78164 (add `textcenter` class)

Comment: Everything is centered inside of the thumbnails but I want to center the THUMBNAILS on the page.

Comment: wrap your code in a <div class="container"> and change col-md-3 to col-md-4?

Comment: @BradWerth okay, but I wonder if a close vote would be a better solution

Answer (score 2):

1. to center your content on the page, wrap the row in a containter ()
2. Notice that Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid. To fill your row with tree thumbs for the   medium (md) grid, consider to use the `col-md-4` class (3 x 4 = 12) class for your columns. ON the small (sm) grid you now have 3 columns of 50% by using three times the `col-sm-6` class. Consider to use only one class, only the `col-md-4` class will give you 3 columns for a screen width of 992px or wider and only the `col-sm-4` class does the same but for screen widths of 768px and wider. Below the 992 or 768 the columns will stack.
3. The text can be centered by applying the `text-center` class, also see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Also see: http://www.bootply.com/WAFUzlJs8s